# set cursor position in contenteditable div in uiwebview

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am loading UIWebView with html file. the html file contains some text in Div tags. I need to set cursor position in a div tag. the html file contains different div tags.based on some condition i need to locate cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

This is helpful for setting the caret position.

Suppose my html is like this:

```
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true">
  text text text<br>text text text<br>text text text<br>
</div>
<button id="button" onclick="setCaret()">focus</button>
```

and my javascript method is:

```
function setCaret() {
    var el = document.getElementById("editable");
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(el.childNodes[2], 5);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    el.focus();
}
```